# Getting range between two wildcards T-sql query syntax

Tags: t-sql, case, wildcard, between, statements

I have a decimal column that i need to to run a wildcard  query on in a case statement but the wildcards will need a between clause that is between one wildcard to another e.g

case when pct between '999.0%' and '700.0%' then 'Top percentile'
how do I write this please

Comment: What do you need that `between 700 and 999` does not provide?

Comment: I have done this as I have arrange of values with different decimal places, but its not working even when I put the % mark to wildcard

Comment: what have you done so far? Could you provide your code, sample data and actual/expected output?

Comment: SELECT
    ITEM ,
     CASE 
       WHEN pct  > = 1000  THEN '1000% '
       WHEN pct BETWEEN '999%' and '800%'  then '999 - 800% '

Comment: table looks like this

Comment: 792.241379310345
692.866666666667
293.75
269
245.9375
197.972972972973
179.782608695652
170
169.711331322706
163.545816733068
159.615384615385
153.213166144201

Comment: [Edit] your post to include such essential info. Don't post it in unformatted comments that may be deleted at any time. And clarify why you think you need wildcards, i.e. what results you get that seem incorrect. There is no clear reason to require wildcards here whatsoever.

Answer (score 1):

Since `pct` is `decimal` then you cannot and you don't need to use the wildcard with it. Just remove the wild cards and the commas `' '`:

```
SELECT ITEM 
  , CASE WHEN pct > = 1000 THEN '1000% ' 
         WHEN pct BETWEEN 800 and 999 then '800 - 999% ' END
FROM table
```

Also `800` should come first instead of 999 in `between`.
You need also `ELSE` for other values less than 800.

Comment: @Spinx - You're welcome any time, please accept the answer if you find it useful .